# Semi-Algebraic Set of Dimension Zero is Finite

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Could someone lend me assistance by explaining why

> a semi-algebraic set has dimension zero $\Leftrightarrow$ it is finite or empty

is true or by giving a reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find it all in   Bochnak,Coste,Roy: Real Algebraic Geometry:

(1) up to semi-algebraic homeomorphism, every semi-algebraic subset
is a disjoint union of finitely many (open) hypercubes
(i.e. sets of the form $]0,1[^d$ for some $d\in\mathbf{N}$).
This is Theorem 2.3.6

(2) a nonempty open semi-algebraic subset of $R^n$ has dimension $n$.
This is Proposition 2.8.4

(3) the dimension of a finite union of semialgebraic sets $A_1,\ldots,A_p$
is $\max(\dim(A_1),\ldots,\dim(A_p))$.
This is Proposition 2.8.5(i)

(4) dimension is invariant under semialgebraic homeomorphism.
This is included in Theorem 2.8.8

Therefore, if a semi-algebraic set is zero-dimensional, its decompositon
as in (1) can only be made up from hypercubes of the form $]0,1[^0$,
i.e. points.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semialgebraic_set) says that "it is not hard to see that a semialgebraic set lies inside an algebraic subvariety of the same dimension". That should suffice.